# How can I change all elements in RecyclerView from an onClick event?

Tags: java, android

I have a `RecyclerView` where each element has an `onClickEventListener()` that changes it's appearance. It works OK, but I actually need to change all other elements appearance. Specifically I need the clicked element to be filled with color and others should only have stroke. I think there is more elegant way of doing this rather than iterating through an array of all elements of the `RecyclerView`.
My current code looks like this:

```
vh.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            GradientDrawable typeShape = (GradientDrawable) vh.mImageView.getDrawable();
            if (vh.clicked) {
                typeShape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff5800"));
            } else {
                typeShape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff5800"));
            }
            vh.clicked = !vh.clicked;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the "best" way to do this involves using a portion of the RecyclerView API that most people are not familiar with: the overloads to e.g. `notifyItemRangeChanged()` that accept a **payload** object.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyitemrangechanged

When you pass a payload object, a special version of `onBindViewHolder()` will be called, and that payload will be passed to this method.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onbindviewholder_5

What all this lets you do is a very efficient re-binding of any displayed ViewHolder objects, and only update the portion of the view that you know has changed.

In your particular example, you could have your adapter track the `selectedPosition` and have your `onBindViewHolder()` method set the background of the item based on whether or not its position is equal to the current selected position:

```
private void updateBackground(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(
        (position == selectedPosition) ? R.drawable.highlight : R.drawable.stroke);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    updateBackground(holder, position);
    // other view binding stuff
}
```

Then you could *also* have an implementation of the special `onBindViewHolder()` call to do partial updates:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    if (payloads != null && payloads.contains("BACKGROUND")) {
        updateBackground(holder, position);
    }
}
```

Once you have both of these set up, any time the selected position is changed you can call:

```
adapter.selectedPosition = 23; // or whatever else
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount(), "BACKGROUND");
```

When you call this special version of `notifyItemRangeChanged()`, the system will invoke your special `onBindViewHolder()` and you'll get a chance to re-draw the background of all the currently-visible views. But you won't waste time updating any not-currently-visible views and you won't waste time binding data that hasn't changed at all (all that "other view binding stuff" from the norma `onBindViewHolder()` implementation).

Comment: You can pass anything you want as a payload. All that matters is that you send _something_ (in this case, the string `"BACKGROUND"`) when you call `notifyItemRangeChanged()` and then check for that same something inside the special `onBindViewHolder()`. Because it doesn't matter at all what you use, it's nice to make it something that's a little helpful; I chose `"BACKGROUND"` because it's an indication that we're only going to change the background of each item. But nothing is stopping you from passing `2` or `Boolean.TRUE` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Create a var to save selection:

```
int selectedItem = -1;// -1 means no selected item by default.
```

Inside your onClickListener:

```
int position = getAdapterPosition();
// Make sure your position is available on your list.
if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
    if (position == selectedItem) {
        return;// Here, I don't want to generate a click event on an already selected item.
    }

    int currentSelected = selectedItem;// Create a temp var to deselect an existing one, if any.
    selectedItem = position;// Check item.

    if (currentSelected != -1) {
        notifiyItemChanged(currentSelected);// Deselected the previous item.
    }

    notifyItemChanged(selectedItem);// Select the current item.
}
```

Finally, whether in your ViewHolder or onBindViewHolder:

```
if (position == selectedItem) {
    // Do action when the item is selected. Change background.
} else {
    // Or on no selected otherwise.
}
```